# using angularjs consecutive ng-include directive

Tags: angularjs

Why using consecutive angular ng-include does not work?

for example:

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/partials/partial1.html'" />
<div data-ng-include="'app/partials/partial2.html'" />
```

only show the content of partial1.html

but if I use:

```
<div>
    <div data-ng-include="'app/partials/partial1.html'" />
</div>
<div>
    <div data-ng-include="'app/partials/partial2.html'" />
</div>
```

Works fine, displays the content of both pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the ending tag for the divs:

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/partials/partial1.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Why did we have to add the closing tag ? Self closing should be sufficient ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: I believe it is a quirk of the (some? most?) HTML parsers.